# G-WAN servlets returning 1-99 (to lack HTTP headers) are very slow

Tags: http-headers, browser, g-wan

I ran **gwan_1** (v3.3.28), and then visited the page *http: //.../?persistence.c*. It reponsed fast.

But when I changed "`return 200`;" to "`return 9;`" in the code, the browser responded slowly, about 4 seconds later.

In the document, it is stated that:

```
To prevent HTTP headers automatic completion, just make your servlets return an  invalid
HTTP status code in the 1-99 range (inclusive).
```

It works but very slowly.

Any idea about this? Is it a bug or I have done something wrong?
I have tried returning 1, 9, and 99. They all give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got it.
This is NOT caused by gwan.
It is the browser behavior.
i used xbuf_frurl() to load the persistence.c, the response was about 0.35 ms. (cpu E2180)

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Browser is WAITING for the server reply. This is a **client timeout**.

Since in this particular case the server does not give the *reply length* in `HTTP headers` (because the **1-99 servlet return value** means *"inject no HTTP-headers if they are missing"*), the client has to wait until it estimates that all should have been transmitted (at which point it displays the result).

You can send any reply *without HTTP headers* when you talk to an Internet Browser with JSON and AJAX (Javascript) because then the format is interpreted differently (JSON VS HTTP).

The G-WAN comet.c demo is using a plain-text message passing exchange with the browser because the Javascript code on the client side reads how long is the server reply (using a format made for this specific application).